# How can I restart a systemd service on graphics changes?

Tags: systemd

I used to run Synergy via an Upstart script that included:

```
start on (login-session-start
          ...
          or drm-device-added
          or drm-device-changed
          or drm-device-removed
          or graphics-device-added
          or graphics-device-changed
          or graphics-device-removed
          ...)

stop on (drm-device-added
         or drm-device-changed
         or drm-device-removed
         or graphics-device-added
         or graphics-device-changed
         or graphics-device-removed
         ...)
```

This would stop and start the service if eg. a monitor was connected or disconnected so that Synergy would detect the new configuration.

I am writing Systemd service files for Synergy, but I can't find what an equivalent mechanism would be. `man systemd.special` doesn't list any graphics related targets, `systemctl list-units --type=device` only shows the graphics adapter (not the monitor) and it's not clear to me how to get Systemd to stop and start a service on a particular event.

How can I do these things? I'm writing it on Ubuntu 16.04, but the more distro agnostic the answer, the better.

Comment: I suspect that `PartOf=` is the answer to my question of how to restart the service, but that depends on the exact nature of whatever mechanism detects display changes.

Comment: Are the directives in `man systemd.path` what you are looking for?

Comment: @MarkStosberg Doesn't look like it, unless there are path events for display configuration changes. I can't find any though.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Actually, some more Googling revealed that the contents of `/sys/class/drm/...` might change on certain events. I'll dig into that.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Nope, can't do it. It requires recursive monitoring and following symlinks, which isn't supported AFAICT.

Comment: One piece of the puzzle: this [udev DRM hotplug rule](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug/blob/master/etc/udev/rules.d/99-monitor-hotplug.rules) or a reduced version: `ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", TAG+="systemd"` ... will cause Systemd to dynamically create units for hotplugged monitors. Maybe there's a way to hook into all of them.